# How to use regular expressions to turn text-based data into CSV

Tags: r, regex, parsing

I want to turn the text data at https://www.bexar.org/DocumentCenter/View/19193/November-6-2018-Election-Totals into a series of dataframes. I'm trying to at least parse the first dataset from the website. I've tried using readLines() and regular expressions in a grep() function, but I need help extracting just the data.

I'm trying to turn this:

```
<HTML>
<PRE>NUMBERED KEY CANVASS                              BEXAR COUNTY, TEXAS                                OFFICIAL RESULTS
                                                  GENERAL, SPECIAL, CHARTER, BON
RUN DATE:11/16/18 03:58 PM                        NOVEMBER 6, 2018
                                                                     WITH 752 OF 752 PRECINCTS REPORTING
                                                   TOTAL  PERCENT                                                    TOTAL  PERCENT
   01 = REGISTERED VOTERS - TOTAL               1104,746             03 = VOTER TURNOUT - TOTAL                              49.96
   02 = BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL                     551,896
                                     - - - - - - - - -
                                       01    02    03
                                     - - - - - - - - -
1001                                  770 . 414 53.77
1002                                  671 . 361 53.80
1003                                 2053  1009 49.15
1004                                  918 . 351 38.24
```

Into a dataframe like this:

```
     01   02   03
1001 770  414  53.77
1002 671  361  53.80
1003 2053 1009 49.15
1004 918  351  38.24
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is useful to see your first efforts and work from there. (Conversely, asking us to do everything from-start is not often a popular type of question.)

Comment: Requires reading `?utils::read.fwf`. Should be straightforward from there. Also probably a duplicate. (The comment just above mine will NOT succeed since there are no commas separating fields.)

Comment: Have you noticed the linked file contains multiple sheets with different formats? You need to be more specific. Potentially you have to split the file into sheets, find the number of columns, extract the column headers, parse the rows accordingly... and so forth.

Comment: Why is this too broad?  It is very specific to a particular input. I am voting to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file into a local file and read that into `L` replacing space, dot with space everywhere giving `L2`.  Then extract lines that begin with a string of digits (possibly preceded by spaces) and succeeded by at least two spaces giving `L3`.  The header lines are the only remaiing lines that begin with a space so split on that giving `Lines.spl` and read in each section using `read.table` giving `DFs`.

Also extract all lines that have an upper case letter or equal signs giving `desc`.  Then split `desc` by the lines of equal signs and drop the last one (as it just has junk) giving `desc.spl`.

At this point `DFs[[i]]` and `desc.spl[[i]]` hold the ith data.frame and the description of it.

```
u <- "https://www.bexar.org/DocumentCenter/View/19193/November-6-2018-Election-Totals"
local.file <- basename(u)
download.file(u, local.file)

L <- readLines(local.file)

L2 <- gsub(" .", " ", L, fixed = TRUE)
L3 <- grep("^ *\\d+  ", L2, value = TRUE)
Lines.spl <- split(L3, cumsum(grepl("^ ", L3)))
DFs <- lapply(Lines.spl, function(x) read.table(text = x, check.names = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

desc <- grep("[A-Z=]", L, value = TRUE)
desc.spl <- head(split(desc, cumsum(grepl("===", desc))), -1)
```

Looking at the beginning of the first table:

```
head(DFs[[1]])
##        01   02    03
## 1001  770  414 53.77
## 1002  671  361 53.80
## 1003 2053 1009 49.15
## 1004  918  351 38.24
## 1005  811  299 36.87
## 1006 2149  876 40.76

desc.spl[[1]]
## [1] "<HTML>"                                                                                                                             
## [2] "<PRE>NUMBERED KEY CANVASS                              BEXAR COUNTY, TEXAS                                OFFICIAL RESULTS"         
## [3] "                                                  GENERAL, SPECIAL, CHARTER, BON"                                                   
## [4] "RUN DATE:11/16/18 03:58 PM                        NOVEMBER 6, 2018"                                                                 
## [5] "                                                                     WITH 752 OF 752 PRECINCTS REPORTING"                           
## [6] "                                                   TOTAL  PERCENT                                                    TOTAL  PERCENT"
## [7] "   01 = REGISTERED VOTERS - TOTAL               1104,746             03 = VOTER TURNOUT - TOTAL                              49.96" 
## [8] "   02 = BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL                     551,896"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This is the foundation I needed to continue the analysis. I have some follow-up questions. I'll start with the grep function resulting in L3. I thought the regular expression ^ *\\d+, would be interpreted like "lines beginning with one space, containing digits". That is not what it does, because it grabs digits from lines that do no begin with spaces. I just really want to understand how you arrived at the solution.

Comment: A `^` matches the start of a string and `*` means zero or more occurrences of the prior character so space star means zero or more spaces.  `?regex` contains a terse discussion of regular expressions in R.